# Clarify rust rayon nested thread pool worker numbers

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing, rayon

I have tried to use `rayon`'s parallel iterators in a *nested* way. As a global pool would have a fixed number of threads, I tend to create an *outer*-pool in `main` and an *inner*-pool each in threads the *outer*-pool spawns.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn stress(index: u32) {
    println!("Runner {} started.", index);
    let mut _x = 0;
    loop {
        _x += 1;
        _x -= 1;
    }
}

fn sub(outer: u32) {
    let inner_pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(1 as usize).build().unwrap();
    inner_pool.install(|| {
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4].into_par_iter().map(|inner| stress(outer * 10 + inner)).collect()
    })
}

fn main() {
    let outer_pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(1 as usize).build().unwrap();
    outer_pool.install(|| vec![1, 2, 3, 4].into_par_iter().map(|outer| sub(outer)).collect())
}
```

As the code tells, I have 16 `stress` jobs which had been split into a 4x4 group to run, and would create an *outer*-pool and an inner one both containing only 1 thread. So what I had expected is only 1 job would run, and only one line (possibly `Runner 11 started.`) would be printed. But I got 3 jobs running in parallel and three lines (`11`, `31` and `41`) printed.

I know [`rayon` tends to cut the jobs in half](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/blob/master/src/iter/plumbing/README.md) so I understand why `31` rather than `21` should appear after `11`, but I couldn't figure out why multiple jobs can run parallel in a literally 1x1 pool.

Also I had tried different pairs for the pool size, but the results still perplex me.

| outer | inner | load |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 9 |
| 1 | 4 | 12 |
| 1 | 16 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 12 |
| 2 | 4 | 16 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 4 | 16 |

Can anyone shed the light on me?

Comment: nit: Your loop is a funny way of writing `loop {}`